# How do you repeatedly initialize a new label in java?

Tags: java, swt

Let's say I want to make a "note taking swt program", so every time I press a button, the program is going to create a new label about 50 pixels lower to the label before. What's an efficient way of implementing that?

Comment: Just create a new label and redo the composite layout. You need to show us what you have tried if you want any more details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it with simple ListView and ObservableList, but observable list isn't necessary. Here is my version of this.

```js
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView<Label> listView;
    private ObservableList<Label> yourList;

    public void initialize() {
        yourList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        listView.setItems(yourList);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(){

        // You can do really bigger processing here

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText("some text maybe");
        label.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        yourList.add(label);
    }
}
```

Result after three times button pressed:

some text maybe
some text maybe
some text maybe

this can come with padding, customizable fonts, color etc.

Hope it helps

Comment: Wait, just realized you want it repeatedly, now editing my answer

Comment: This looks like JavaFX, the question is asking about SWT

Comment: Yeah, but the idea is the same i guess

Comment: Used the concept, worked perfectly after some edits, thanks!